# How do I connect to different Postgresql database schemas using PowerBI?

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, connection

I have two schemas within a single PostgreSQL database, Production and Test, that I'm trying to connect to in Power BI.  I'm able to successfully connect to the Production schema without any issue, but for some reason it's not also seeing the Test schema even though it's on the same database. I'm using pgAdmin 4 on the PostgreSQL side and confirmed that the Security setup on both schemas is the same in case the issue is related to access, but Power BI still doesn't show any tables within the Test schema when I make the connection.

Can anyone tell me what I might be missing so that I can connect to the Test schema as well?  I feel like I'm missing something very simple, but haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Elaborate on the "not also seeing" part. Are you simply not able to connect/find to the Test database (even in a new PBIX without Production connected)? Are you doing Import or Direct Query?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To clarify, I'm connecting using Import, but whenever I make the connection, it only pulls up the Production schema.  So the only tables I can import are on that schema.  None of the tables on the Test schema are displayed even though that schema is on the same database.